# Having troubles sending emails from spring boot application

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I have been trying to send email via spring boot and i cant seem to succeed. I am been using javamail api for a long time now but want to use springboot with spring mail.

```
public class SendMail {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    public void sendingMail(String to, String subject, String body) {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(body);
        javaMailSender.send(message);
    }

}
```

and here is my mailer

```
@Controller
public class ExamPle {

    @Autowired
    private SendMail  sendMail;

    @RequestMapping("/he")
    public String homePage() {
        sendMail.sendingMail("bobobush007@gmail.com", "Welcome George", "Sample Message here");
        return "Sent";
        }
}
```

I already have sprint-boot-starter-mail in my pom file but i keep getting this error message. I have even watched youtube videos of tutorials on how to do this and yet it doesn't work. I am using Spring Tool Suite Version: 3.9.0.RELEASE.

Properties file

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=my-email-address
spring.mail.password=my-password
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.defaultEncoding=UTF-8
```

> 2017-09-14 05:25:57.811  INFO 12576 --- [           main]
>   com.example.demo.EmaildemoApplication    : Starting
>   EmaildemoApplication on Georges-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 12576
>   (started by georgetebo in /Users/georgetebo/STS Projects/Emaildemo)
>   2017-09-14 05:25:57.814  INFO 12576 --- [           main]
>   com.example.demo.EmaildemoApplication    : No active profile set,
>   falling back to default profiles: default 2017-09-14 05:25:57.845 
>   INFO 12576 --- [           main]
>   ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3d3fcdb0:
>   startup date [Thu Sep 14 05:25:57 WAT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>   2017-09-14 05:25:58.652  INFO 12576 --- [           main]
>   s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with
>   port(s): 8080 (http) 2017-09-14 05:25:58.662  INFO 12576 --- [
>   main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service
>   [Tomcat] 2017-09-14 05:25:58.662  INFO 12576 --- [           main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine:
>   Apache Tomcat/8.5.20 2017-09-14 05:25:58.714  INFO 12576 ---
>   [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       :
>   Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext 2017-09-14
>   05:25:58.714  INFO 12576 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext:
>   initialization completed in 871 ms 2017-09-14 05:25:58.821  INFO 12576
>   --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/] 2017-09-14 05:25:58.823 
>   INFO 12576 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter:
>   'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*] 2017-09-14 05:25:58.824  INFO 12576
>   --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*] 2017-09-14
>   05:25:58.824  INFO 12576 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter:
>   'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*] 2017-09-14 05:25:58.824  INFO
>   12576 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   :
>   Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*] 2017-09-14
>   05:25:58.848  WARN 12576 --- [           main]
>   ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'examPle': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'sendMail'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo.SendMail' available:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
>   Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   2017-09-14 05:25:58.850  INFO 12576 --- [           main]
>   o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
>   2017-09-14 05:25:58.861  INFO 12576 --- [           main]
>   utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration
>   report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2017-09-14
>   05:25:58.927 ERROR 12576 --- [           main]
>   o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field sendMail in com.example.demo.ExamPle required a bean of type
>   'com.example.demo.SendMail' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.SendMail' in your
>   configuration.

This is my Pom file

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.mailsender</groupId>
<artifactId>MailSender</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>MailSender</name>
<description>ZemoPoint for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have uninstalled my jdk as well as STS and installed new copies.Now i get this error

Comment: check your pom file and see if javax.mail has been accidentally marked as 'provided'; therefore it is missing at runtime

Comment: Please post the contents your pom.xml file. Without it it's very hard to determine why you're getting this error.

Comment: @ spiritwalker  @g00glen00b     pom file added as requested.

Comment: This is weird, I'm using exactly the same code and I'm not experiencing this error. There must be an issue in your IDE I think. Can you try running it using Maven? (execute `mvn spring-boot:run` on the commandline)

Comment: I have tried on new installs of eclipse and STS and still getting same error. I am using macOS Sierra   @g00glen00b  can u please let me know what IDE you using and version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

```
@Service
public class SendMail {

@Autowired
private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

  public void sendingMail(String to, String subject, String body) {
    MimeMessage message=javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper;
    helper=new MimeMessageHelper(message,true);
    helper.setTo(to);
    helper.setSubject(subject);
    helper.setText(body);
    javaMailSender.send(message);

 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding javax.mail to your pom ? Spring email sender has a dependency to JavaMail.

Comment: Shouldn't matter, `spring-boot-starter-mail` already includes the mail API implementation: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/eb4a9d87fde2579e1221a4faed3c0b432937fdd1/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-mail/pom.xml#L34-L37

Comment: I see the same problem you need to add javax.mail ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException

Answer (score 0):

I think the password you should use is the Generated app password for gmail, it shouldn't be just any password i guess.

Comment: Marc, what makes you think that the original poster is not using the correct password?  I don't see anything along those lines in the error message.

Answer (score -1):

Seems your properties is not fetched properly, for example:

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

You should try to use other way like this:

```
JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

mailSender.setHost(emailProperties.getHost());
mailSender.setPort(Integer.parseInt(emailProperties.getPort()));
mailSender.setUsername(emailProperties.getUsername());
mailSender.setPassword(emailProperties.getPassword());

Properties javaMailProperties = new Properties();
javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
javaMailProperties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
javaMailProperties.put("mail.debug", "true");

mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties);
```

See more this way from the post [Spring Boot Freemarker Email Template](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-boot-tutorial/spring-boot-freemarker-email-template.html)

Hope this help!