# JavaMailSender object is not sending an email in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, smtp, gmail

I want to implement forgot password functionality. My app should send an email to the employee. Method send() of my JavaMailSender object is not working, and I don't receive any exception message. I've tried a lot of things. For example:

[Having troubles sending emails from spring boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187335/having-troubles-sending-emails-from-spring-boot-application)

[No exception found but mail not send in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003399/no-exception-found-but-mail-not-send-in-spring-mvc)

[Java spring boot - JavaMailSender errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46023973/java-spring-boot-javamailsender-errors)

My ForgotPasswordController.java class (part that has a problem):

```
@PostMapping("/forgot_password")
    public String processForgotPassword(HttpServletRequest request, Model model)
    {
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String token = RandomString.make(30);

        
        try 
        {
            employeeDAO.updateResetPasswordToken(token, email);
            String resetPasswordLink = Utility.getSiteURL(request) + "/reset_password?token=" + token;

            sendEmail(email, resetPasswordLink);
            model.addAttribute("message", "We have sent a reset password link to your email. Please check.");
             
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            model.addAttribute("error", "Error while sending email");
        }
             
        return "forgot_password_form";
    }
    
    public void sendEmail(String recipientEmail, String link) throws Exception
    {
        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();              
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
         
        helper.setFrom(new InternetAddress("svemir2212@gmail.com"));
        helper.setTo(recipientEmail);
         
        String subject = "Here's the link to reset your password";
         
        String content = "<p>Hello,</p>"
                + "<p>You have requested to reset your password.</p>"
                + "<p>Click the link below to change your password:</p>"
                + "<p><a href=\"" + link + "\">Change my password</a></p>"
                + "<br>"
                + "<p>Ignore this email if you do remember your password, "
                + "or you have not made the request.</p>";
         
        helper.setSubject(subject);
         
        helper.setText(content, true);
         
        mailSender.send(message);
    }
```

I'm using Spring Boot. Here is my config for email in application.properties file:

```
spring.mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port = 465
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8
spring.mail.username = mymail@gmail.com
spring.mail.password = somepassword
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class = javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback = false
```

I've tried with port 587 also, doesn't work.